# Play Again Code Problems

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having problems with code let's someone "play again". Here's the code:

```
playing = True
while playing:
    game()
    play_again = raw_input("Would you like to play again? Y|N").lower
    if (play_again == "n"):
        playing = False
```

However, after I type "n" or "N", the game plays again anyway. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stored the `str.lower` method, *not the result*. Add `()` to actually *call* that method:

```
raw_input("Would you like to play again? Y|N").lower()
```

Python methods are objects just like everything else, you can store those just like you can store a string:

```
>>> 'NO'.lower
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x1058d8c88>
>>> 'NO'.lower()
'no'
```

Instead of using a flag variable, use `break` to exit the loop, and `True` to make the loop endless:

```
while True:
    game()
    play_again = raw_input("Would you like to play again? Y|N").lower
    if play_again == "n":
        break
```

Here the `break` keyword will end the loop *right there* without first having to loop back to the top and testing a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
    play_again = raw_input("Would you like to play again? Y|N ").strip().lower()
```